# Socket.io Client Side socket.io@0.9.16

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My problem is that I can connect to my client via html/js but I cannot do the same thing using node. I am using socket.io@0.9.16 .

```
var io       = require('socket.io');

var socket = io.connect('https://website.com:3000');

socket.on('connect', function (data) {
    socket.emit('room', 'connecting');
})

socket.on('message' , function (data){
    console.log("message has been sent");
});
```

vs

```
<html>

<script src="https://website.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect('https://website.com:3000');

    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        socket.emit('room', 'connecting');
    })

    socket.on('message' , function (data){
        alert(data.message);
    });
</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm install socket.io-client@0.9.16

```
 var io       = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io.connect('https://website:3000')    ;

  socket.on('connect', function (data) {
  socket.emit('room', 'foo');
  console.log('connecting... working...')
});

socket.on('someRoom' , function (data){
  console.log('update ...');
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `socket.io`, you need to use [socket.io-client](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client#nodejs-server-side-usage).

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('https://website.com:3000');

socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('room', 'connecting');

    socket.on('message' , function (data){
        alert(data.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, Ben I believe the piece of code you're using references v1.0.6 but I'm using v0.9.16 .